# How to capture screenshot on test case failure for Python Unittest

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, python-3.6, pytest, python-unittest

I am using Python 3.6.5 with the following libraries:

- Appium-Python-Client==0.26
- unittest2==1.1.0
- selenium==3.5.0
- pytest==3.6.3

Now I need to capture the screenshot in case of test failure, So intentionally I did put a false statement 
    `self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector('test')` .

I am using `sys.exc_info()`. But when I executing below code using a command: `py.test untitled.py` or `python3 -m unittest untitled.py` it does not capturing it.

Code:

```
import sys, time, unittest2
from selenium import webdriver

class FB360(unittest2.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()

    def test_user_can_login(self):
            self.driver.get('https://www.google.co.in')
            self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector('test')

    def tearDown(self):
        print(sys.exc_info())
        if sys.exc_info()[0]:
            test_method_name = self._testMethodName
            self.driver.save_screenshot(test_method_name + str(time.time()) + '.png')
        self.driver.quit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest2.main()
```

**O/P:**

> (None, None, None)
>
> E
>
> ======================================================================
>   ERROR: test_user_can_login (untitled.FB360)
>
> ---
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/Volumes/Harry/Projects/pythonScreenshots/untitled.py", line 11, in test_user_can_login
>       self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector('test')
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 498, in find_element_by_css_selector
>       return self.find_element(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR, value=css_selector)
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 832, in find_element
>       'value': value})['value']
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 297, in execute
>       self.error_handler.check_response(response)
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 194, in check_response
>       raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
>   selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"test"}
>     (Session info: chrome=67.0.3396.99)
>     (Driver info: chromedriver=2.40.565386 (45a059dc425e08165f9a10324bd1380cc13ca363),platform=Mac OS X 10.13.5 x86_64)

**My Foundings:**

- `print(sys.exc_info())` prints: (None, None, None). That means my test case is passed even if I am receiving below exception:

> selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"test"}

- As `sys.exc_info())`  returns (None, None, None) execution won't done under `if` condition

So my major concern is why `sys.exc_info())`  returns (None, None, None) even if I am receiving NoSuchElementException ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting Python's unittest results in a tearDown() method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4414234/getting-pythons-unittest-results-in-a-teardown-method)

Comment: The `sys.exc_info()` trick won't work in Python 3, so skip the accepted answer in the linked question and read through the rest. You could get much better solutions using `pytest`s fixtures, but it looks like you're writing pure `unittest` tests and only using `pytest` as test runner.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, exactly I have written pure unittest and using pytest as test runner.
Could you suggest me the best library for Python3 to make UI testcases with selenium ?

Comment: I don't think that any library will supersede `selenium`; most of the routine code around tests is too project-specific.

Answer (score 6):

I use this to take screenshots of failed tests

```
@pytest.fixture()
def browser(request):
    options = Options()
    options.add_argument("--headless")  # Runs Chrome in headless mode.
    _chrome = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
    failed_before = request.session.testsfailed
    yield _chrome
    if request.session.testsfailed != failed_before:
        test_name = request.node.name
        take_screenshot(_chrome, test_name)
    _chrome.close()


def take_screenshot(browser, test_name):
    screenshots_dir = "path_to/functional_tests/failure_screenshots"
    screenshot_file_path = "{}/{}.png".format(screenshots_dir, test_name)
    browser.save_screenshot(
        screenshot_file_path
    )
```

Comment: The tests have to use this same fixture for browsing, right? Otherwise I get all blank screenshots.